# Radio buttons are not populated by data in Object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button

Complete novice here with one question.

I am creating app with some data. On `FirstPage` there is `Picker` with some data (objects) that user can choose. Selected data (object) is then passed to `SecondPage` and this page is populated with data from this object. While entry/text is populated correctly, radio buttons are not. After playing around for few hours (creating simple testing project and creating various scenarios) I noticed following:

Issue is when I am populating data from SQL database. If I create `ObservableCollection` and add data with code then this works, but if I populate data from SQL then it does not. Please note that I did not change anything on `SecondPage` (page showing data) only how objects are added to `ObservableCollectin` on `FirstPage`.

Also binding works, because if I change selection and save, data is saved to Object. If I load object again radio buttons do not display option saved.

Does anyone have any solution for this? Or at least idea why radio buttons are not populated when objects is added from SQL?

my code (I use FreshMVVM and rg.plugins.popup)

FIRST PAGE

PageModel

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using FreshMvvm;
using RadioButtonTest.Model;
using RadioButtonTest.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FreshMvvm.Popups;

namespace RadioButtonTest
{
    class FirstPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public async override void Init(object initData)
        {
            DatabaseConnection database = await DatabaseConnection.Instance;
            var c = await database.GetAllCategories();

            Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(c); //If objects are
            added like this radio buttons are not populated

            // If objects are added like below radio buttons are populated
            Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 5, CategoryName = "Name
            one", FlowType = "1" });
            Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "Name
            two", FlowType = "2" });
            Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2, CategoryName = "Name
            three", FlowType = "1" });
            Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 3, CategoryName = "Name
            four", FlowType = "0" });
            Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 4, CategoryName = "Name
            five", FlowType = "2" });
        }

        public Command GoToTestPage
        {
            get => new Command(async () =>
            await CoreMethods.PushPopupPageModel<SecondPageModel>(ChosenObject));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Category> categories;

        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
        {
            get => categories;
            set
            {
                categories = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Category chosenObject;

        public Category ChosenObject
        {
            get => chosenObject;
            set
            {
                chosenObject = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="RadioButtonTest.FirstPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenObject}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
            <Button Text="Go to test Page"
                Command="{Binding GoToTestPage}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SECOND PAGE

PageModel

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using FreshMvvm;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FreshMvvm.Popups;
using RadioButtonTest.Model;

namespace RadioButtonTest
{
    class SecondPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public async override void Init(object initData)
        {
            Category mT = (Category)initData;
            ChosenObject = mT;
        }

        private Category chosenObject;

        public Category ChosenObject
        {
            get => chosenObject;
            set
            {
                chosenObject = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Command CancelCategory => new Command(async () =>
        {
            await CoreMethods.PopPopupPageModel();
        });
    }
}
```

Page

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="RadioButtonTest.SecondPage"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:inputLayout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TextInputLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
    CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False"
    Padding="20">
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Padding="20">
        <Label TextColor="Black"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding CategoryPopupText}" />
        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Hint="Category" >
            <Entry Text="{Binding CategorySelected.CategoryName}"/>
        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
            RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="TEST"
            RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding ChosenObject.FlowType,
            Mode=TwoWay}">
            <RadioButton Content="Op 1"
                Value="0" />
            <RadioButton Content="Op 2"
                Value="1" />
            <RadioButton Content="Op 3"
                Value="2"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCategory}"/>
            <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCategory}"/>
            <Button Text="Delete"
                Command="{Binding DeleteCategorytWarning}"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                TextColor="Red"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsDeleteCategoryVisible}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: please properly format your code so that it is readable

Comment: Thanks. Noted for next time.

Comment: `Issue is when I am populating data from SQL database.`  Please recheck if you can get the data from your sql database correctly before navigating to the second page.

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT I do not know how to check it I get data from my SQL database correctly. I reviewed and see that before navigation to second page all data is in object - as you can see from [image](https://imgur.com/a/Y5LCAqI)

Comment: If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so  that we can test on our side?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT No problem, here it is https://github.com/Bumbar14/RadioButtonTest
Also big thank you for taking time in helping me:)

Comment: I think you missed uploading some files. What's the `Category`,`Account`  and `FlowType` 
 and `Transaction` ?

Comment: Updated. Hope now is more clear

Comment: But how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps so that we can reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: On first page you have 3 visual elements. Picker, and two buttons. With Picker you can choose entry, with button "Go to test page" you open entry (to see if radio buttons function works) and with "Add new SQL" button you can add new entry to SQL database. 
To reproduce issue first, you need to add new entry to SQL. You do that with clicking "Add new SQL". In popup you add custom name and select one option from 3 radio buttons. You can click save. Then on First page you can select entry with picker, one that you added, or one that is "hardcoded" and click "Go to test page". @Jessie Zhang -MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Radio buttons are not populated by data in Object
```

If you want to populate the three `RadioButton`s correctly in `SecondPageFrom`, you can bind the three fields(`RB_first`,`RB_second` and `RB_third`) in class `SecondPageModel` to the three `RadioButton`s.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="TEST"
                             RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding ChosenObject.FlowType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           >
        <RadioButton Content="Op 1" IsChecked="{Binding RB_first}"
                                     Value="0" />
        <RadioButton Content="Op 2" IsChecked="{Binding RB_second}"
                                     Value="1"
                                     />
        <RadioButton Content="Op 3" IsChecked="{Binding RB_third}"
                                     Value="2"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

In addition,please do not comment out method  `Workaround();` in `SecondPageModel`

```
       void Workaround()
    {
        switch (ChosenObject.FlowType)
        {
            case "0":
                RB_first = true;
                break;
            case "1":
                RB_second = true;
                break;
            case "2":
                RB_third = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works. I thought this is not needed and RadioButtons will be populated from Object. Looks like they needs separate method to set them checked.